# How to disable auto-complete without disabling suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I tried messing with preference settings for unity and c# intellisense but it didnt have any effect rather then fixing stuff that isnt broken.(*breaking more)
I tried solutions that i searched on the net but no luck.

Lets say I am creating an int Account; variable
when I write Acc and press space or enter vs autocompletes it to 
AccelerationEvent.

I know I could do it without pressing to space but I tend to press space a lot while coding. It helps me to understand what am I doing.

It is very annoying and time consuming to switch from keyboard to mouse to delete it and rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to disable this. From Visual Studio, go to *Edit* ---> *IntelliSense* ---> *Toggle Completion Mode*.

The shortcut for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Now, typing "Acc", you can no longer complete it by pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

This answer is verified with *Visual Studio 2015*. Might be different on other versions but give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using VS2017 and edit menu doesnt include anything usefull. However, intellisense options are at Tools >> Options >> TextEditor >> C# >>IntelliSense.   I have tried every settings available but none of them disabled space to complete.It seems like it isn't possible to disable that option without disabling IntelliSense. At least I corrected every settings to my likings while I was at it. I already knew Ctrl+alt+space but thank you anyway, it is also possible to press ESC instead Ctrl+alt+space. I think I am going to have to get used to that :)    Thank you again.